# Minimal polynomial of a change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is simple, but I still have a hard time to get it right: What is the minimal polynomial of
$$
\phi: \text{Mat}(n \times n, \mathbb{F}) \rightarrow \text{Mat}(n \times n, \mathbb{F}), \quad 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \quad & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \quad & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}\\
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$?

This must be some change of basis, such that $A = SAS^{-1}$. This problem is an exercise I found on an exercise sheet for linear algebra. My initial idea was to write down the transformation matrix $M_{B}^{B}(\phi)$, for the basis $B = \{E_{11}, \ldots, E_{nn}\}$. The basis contains $n^2$ matrices. The result will be a matrix like this
$$
M_{B}^{B}(\phi) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \mathbf{1} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \quad & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \mathbf{1}\\
\mathbf{1} & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and then I would compute the characteristic equation
$$
\det(M_{B}^{B}(\phi)-X\mathbf{1}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
-X & \mathbf{1} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \quad & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \mathbf{1}\\
\mathbf{1} & \cdots & 0 & -X\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and that is the point where I am stuck. I am not sure how to compute this.

Comment: Need to add more context. What have you tried? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to get the matrices right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$\phi^n(A)-A=0.$$
Therefore $m_{\phi}(x)|x^n-1.$ On the other hand, the linear transformations $\textrm{Id},\phi,\phi^2,...,\phi^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F},$ since $\textrm{Id}(E_{11}),\phi(E_{11}),...,\phi^{n-1}(E_{11})$ are independent over $\mathbb{F}.$ No polynomial of degree less than $n$ in $\phi$ can give $0$, so $m_{\phi}(x)=x^n-1.$